# Performing a global lock in a Python web application?

Tags: python, redis, uwsgi

Basically, I have the following problem. There is a order processing system which handles payments. In very rare circumstances, we end up with double orders because while we query the credit card handler via the API, if the user refreshes the page really quickly, the credit card processor sometimes responds to both requests as "**success**" and we get two successful "paid" events in the system.

So my idea was to implement a lock around the payment stuff (per order) and if the lock is locked, tell the customer off (which would happen if the customer refreshes the page very quickly - I think in our case it was actually intentional).

So I thought about doing it with Redis and came up with this:

```
def _PaymentInterlock(object):
    def __init__(self, pp):
        self.key = GlobalKey('pay_ilk_%s'%pp._ident)

    def lock(self):
        self.key(1)

    def unlock(self):
        self.key.delete()

    def try_lock(self):
        result = self.key()
        if result == 1:
            return False
        self.lock()
        return True
```

The only problem with this is that the **try_lock** operation would not be atomic (as opposed to a real *compare and store* operation), so technically, two WSGI workers could get a key miss and then both lock the "lock" causing the same sort of problem.

Are the any suggestions on how I would tackle this sort of a problem?

Comment: this sounds similar to a debounce circuit in electronics. You are on the right path in my opinion. If you find some sort of way to associate a unique user with a transaction, just slap the lock on THEIR unique id, until a result is received

Comment: For what are you processing payments? Is this like an Amazon purchase where a customer is purchasing distinct products with unique skus or identifiers? I have an idea but it depends on accessing the order details, similar to Eli's answer, but without locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking in Redis is actually quite easy due to its single-threaded nature. Just use [SetNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx). There's more info on that linked page, but the basic idea is:

1. Client1 asks for a lock. If it gets it, it sets the lock name to be some unique transaction_id. The value should be the current time.
2. Client2 (maybe it's the user refreshing) asks for a lock on the same name. It doesn't receive it.
3. As a backoff measure, client2 checks the timestamp on the lock. If it's surpassed some max_time, that means for some reason client1 didn't properly release its lock, so we give the lock to client2 anyway with a new timestamp. Otherwise, client2 is out of luck, and doesn't proceed.
4. Client1 finishes whatever it was doing (the transaction, in your case) and releases the lock, so now it's accessible again in case the user wants to do something else with the transaction.

Here's a simplified/modified version of this design pattern. I use something very similar in production:

```
def getRedisLock(name, max_time, r):
    lock = r.setnx(name, int(time.mktime(time.gmtime())))
    if not lock:
        lock_time = int(r.get(name))
        #if the lock expired (assume some client failed)
        if lock_time + max_time < int(time.mktime(time.gmtime())):
            old_time = int(r.getset(name, int(time.mktime(time.gmtime()))))
            if old_time == lock_time:
                lock = True
    #If you still have no lock, do something special here, if you want
    if not lock:
        pass
    return lock

def releaseRedisLock(self, name):
    r = self.r
    return r.delete(name)
```

Just call getRedisLock() with some unique transaction_id prior to each transaction. Only process the credit card if you get a lock, otherwise tell the user to stop being a jerk :)